# Show that $\{p \in \Delta^n \mid b^T p + p^T Ap \leq \alpha\}$ is a convex set.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

Show that $S := \{p \in \Delta^n \mid b^T p + p^T Ap \leq \alpha\}$ is a convex set where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $A\succeq 0$, $\Delta^n$ is the probability simplex.

I have been stuck for this for hours. My main approach is to take two points $p, q \in S$ and show that $\lambda p + (1-\lambda) q \in S$, but the formula becomes very complicated to manage.

I am wondering if there is an easier approach.

Comment: It is rarely necessary to resort to first principles. For instance, if you define $f(p)=b^TP+p^TAp$, then it's trivial to show that is a convex function; and then any superlevel-set $f(p)\leq \alpha$ is also a convex set. And then that intersecting with the simplex $\Delta^n$ gets you the rest of the way.

Comment: Fix $t$ in $(0,1)$ and $p$ and $q$ in $\mathbb R^n$, and consider $$D=tp^TAp+(1-t)q^TAq-(tp+(1-t)q)^TA(tp+(1-t)q)$$ then $$D=t(1-t)(p^TAp+q^TAq-p^TAq-q^TAp)=t(1-t)(p-q)A(p-q)^T$$ Can you finish, that is, show that $$D\geqslant0\ ?$$